# linux ELF section and header access permission

Tags: linux, memory, permissions, elf, readelf

In my understanding, ELF header is for program execution view.
section is for linker's view.

but linux command 'readelf' shows that there are
memory access permission flag for each section (AWX)
and each header (RWE).

the book say's more than one of section is merged into single header.
what happens if when linker merges more than one section into single header
and each section has different access permission flags??

and what is the relationship between access permission in /proc/[pid]/maps
such as

```
root@declspec-desktop:/tmp# cat /proc/1951/maps
004a5000-005f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 511     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
005f8000-005fa000 r--p 00153000 08:01 511     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
005fa000-005fb000 rw-p 00155000 08:01 511     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so
```

and access permission in section and header??

how does these permissions (in `/proc/[pid]/maps`) determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding for your example above, permissions in /proc//maps are the permissions associated with different sections. For example, in the above snippet, entry with permissions - 'r-xp' gives the address of .text segment (location where code is present.) For this reason, if you check, it does not contain 'w' permission as we are not supposed to write new code in an executing binary. 
So, in your above example -

```
004a5000-005f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 511     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so - TEXT AREA which contains executable code

005f8000-005fa000 r--p 00153000 08:01 511     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so - Area that contains read only variables or constants (.rodata data)

005fa000-005fb000 rw-p 00155000 08:01 511     /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.1.so - Area where we have variables used by program i.e. (.data)
```

Sorry, i could not follow your other question. Can you please elaborate? Also, which book are you talking about?

Comment: when linker makes executable, the book says(its a compiler book, not famous..) sections will be merged into segment.  but readelf shows that each section has it's own permission and each segments also has it's own permission.  now let's say section A has permission RW-, and section B has permission R--.  if a segment C is merged from section A, B, what permission does C has to have?? R--?? or RW-??

Comment: I know "why" .text section requires only r-x permission and .data section requires rw- permission.  what I am curious is that "how" does the permission determined from /proc/pid.  assume that there is a section ".hello" inside executable ELF file.  based on what does the permission in /proc/pid determined??

Comment: There cannot be a .hello section. Sections are predefined and all binaries have same sections.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that the program header (or segment) contains the bitwise-or of the permissions of the sections which were merged into it.
So in your example if a RW- section was merged with a R-- section into  one segment, it would end up being RW-. To avoid this you would arrange to have them in unique segments.

If you had a '.hello' section (which is indeed possible!) then it's entry in the memory map depends on which segment contains it. The permissions would be at least as strict as the sections, but may be looser, if there are also other sections with additional permissions in the same segment.

But to me - it's not clear why anyone is talking about how a 'section' ends up in an 'executable'. As OP mentions, sections are for linking, and segments are for loading. It's fine to have an ELF with no sections and still load and run properly. /proc/map lines *only* correspond to the segment table